# import excel in sql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel, mysqli

Code:

```
{
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "refe_book");
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["import"]))
{
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["excel"]["name"])); // For getting 
Extension of selected file
$allowed_extension = array("xls", "xlsx", "csv"); //allowed extension
if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension)) //check selected file extension 
is present in allowed extension array
{
$file = $_FILES["excel"]["tmp_name"]; // getting temporary source of excel file
include("PHPExcel/Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php"); // Add PHPExcel Library in this code
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file); // create object of PHPExcel 
library by using load() method and in load method define path of selected file

$output .= "<label class='text-success'>Data Inserted</label><br /><table 
class='table table-bordered'>";
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
{
$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
$ins_flag = 0;
$company_name = "";
for($row=1; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
{
if ($ins_flag == 1)
{
$output .= "<tr>";
$alias = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());
$company_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());
$product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());
$unit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue());
$mrp = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue());

if ($product_name[$row][1] == null)
{
$company_name = $alias[$row][0];
}
else if ($product_name[$row][1] != null)
{
$query = "INSERT INTO refe_book_table(alias, company_name, product_name, unit, mrp) VALUES ('".$alias."', '".$company_name."', '".$product_name."', '".$unit."', '".$mrp."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        $output .= '<td>'.$alias.'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$company_name.'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$unit.'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$mrp.'</td>';
        $output .= '</tr>';
     }
   }

}
} 
$output .= '</table>';

}
else
{
$output = '<label class="text-danger">Invalid File</label>'; //if non excel file then
}
}
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Import Excel to Mysql using PHPExcel in PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
  body
  {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   background-color:#f1f1f1;
  }
  .box
  {
  width:700px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-top:100px;
 }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container box">
  <h3 align="center">Import Excel to Mysql using PHPExcel in PHP</h3><br />
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label>Select Excel File</label>
   <input type="file" name="excel" />
   <br />
   <input type="submit" name="import" class="btn btn-info" value="Import" />
  </form>
  <br />
  <br />
  <?php
  echo $output;
  ?>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
}
```

Error:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\referencebook\index.php on line 6
>   Error: not importing data

Source file:

[image: Source file]

After importing it want's to import in mysql like this image:

[image: Sql import]

in above code source excel file is imported and the data should sorted like Sql import image
the data is not importing in MySQL and also not showing in browser

Comment: Have you tried debugging your own code? SO is a terrible debugger!

Comment: You **really** have to indent your code.  It is very hard to figure out the context blocks like this.  Then you start your code with '{' and finish it with '}'.  That is not valid in an HTML or PHP file.  Lastly for your screen prints, include them in the question otherwise if the links become dead, the question will be useless for future research.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass anything other than a variable into `end()`, you are passing a function into it, but internally PHP is expecting a variable.

Changing your `end()` to the following should work

```
$fileName = explode(".", $_FILES["excel"]["name"]);
$extension = end($fileName);
```